# what is difference between vector<int> v(N) and vector < int > v [N]?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, stl

What is `vector< int > v(N)` ?

1. Is it an array which can have the maximum size of `N` (like `vector<int> v`)?
2. is it same as `vector<int> v[N]`?

I think it is the first one(correct me if I am wrong).

What is `vector< vector< int > > V(N)`? Is it like 2D array with maximum size `N`?
What is the difference between `vector < int > v[N]` and `vector< vector< int > >v(N)`?

Comment: "Is it a dynamic array which can have the maximum size of N(like vector v)?" - _array_ means something quite particular in C++, and while a vector behaves much like an array, it is not an array.  You should re-word your question.

Comment: Seriously not even the slightest effort made. [`vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) (3).

Comment: Dynamic was in case of size not with dynamic values . sorry for writing dynamic array

Comment: The downvotes **raining** down on this one should tell you there is something *inherently* wrong with your question. **Could you at least stop editing it**, because every single of your edits invalidates the answer?

Comment: Even though the question is terrible, I wouldn't advise to close it since it got a good answer.

Comment: In its current state, this seems a reasonable question which has attracted a good answer.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming that

- `N` is some kind of integer,
- there is an `#include <vector>` somewhere,
- there is either a `using namespace std;` or a `using std::vector;` somewhere...

This is the declaration of an object `v`, of type `std::vector< int >`, initialized to hold `N` objects (of type `int`), which are default-initialized (i.e., indeterminate, since `int` is a POD type for which no default initialization is defined).

[Documentation of `vector` constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) -- this one is case (2).

[Spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) -- which needs some adapting to C++ but is still a good start.

It is **not** "a dynamic array line `vector v`", it **is** a vector.

And no, it is **not** the same as `vector v[N]` (which would not even compile). It is *also* **not** the same as `vector<int> v[N]` -- that would be an array of `N` different `vector<int>` objects.

---

> Now if it is the first one then what is `vector< vector< int > > V(N)` ?

Since it's **not** the first one, do I still have to answer this? :-D

```
vector< vector< int > > V(N);
```

That is the declaration of an object `V` of type `vector< vector< int > >`, i.e. "vector of int-vectors", initialized to hold `N` default-initialized objects...

...i.e., a vector holding `N` objects of `vector< int >` -- which are, in turn, empty (because "empty" is what default-initialized vectors are).

---

C++ has...

- The **array** (`int v[N];`), which works exactly like the C array.
- The **std::vector** (`std::vector< int > v;`), which is dynamic in size.
- The **std::array** (`std::array< int, N >;`), which is static in size like the C array, but does offer some of the niceties of `std::vector`.

You need to be exact about what you are referring to. These are quite distinct types with a distinct feature set.

---

**UPDATE:**

With your latest couple of edits, it became clear that your **real** question is:

> What is a `vector`?

It's a C++ class template implementing a container that can hold contiguous elements of a given type (*like* a C array), but is dynamically-sized (*unlike* a C array).

[See the documentation.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Generally speaking, you don't use C arrays in C++ code anymore, except for some *really* special cases. You use `std::string` for strings, and `std::vector` for (almost) everything else you used arrays for in C.

Comment: is vector < vector < int > > like vector < int > v[N]  ?

Comment: @SammeeSharma: I strongly suggest you pick up [a good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242). A `std::vector` is to a C-style array like a 2015 Sedan to a Ford T. Yes, both hold contiguous objects and are commonly accessed via `v[ index ]`, but that is about as far as similarities go. And *try* to refer to the documentation of the types you are using...

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector<int> v(N)`declares a variable `v` with the type of `std::vector<int>` and initializes the vector's size to hold `N` ints which are default initialized, meaning in this case that their initial value is undefined.

`std::vector` is a template from the C++ standard library which implements a resizable array whose elements are stored contiguously in memory. It is essentially a safer alternative to C arrays.

Comment: Upvoted for the avatar alone. :-D

Comment: Thanks, and yes, I am positive that default initialized non-POD types are initialized to indeterminate values, which is a better word than saying that the initial value is undefined. Either way, it follows the general C++ rule of "You don't pay for what you don't use". See here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization -- If you want, you could provide the initial value to the constructor as the second argument, though.

Comment: Yes, found the info (on that very page...) and edited the quesion out of my comment (and the clarification into my answer). Since I am pretty OCD about initializing my values, the matter just never came up for me. ;-)