# Regarding vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

I have used a vector as: `vector<int> v(2)`

Now I have pushed digit 1 to the vector.

Now when I will try to print the elements of v then the output will be as
0 0 1
Why the leading 2 zeroes are coming although I have not pushed them to the vector?

Comment: Because you've created a vector of size `2` and so the elements will contain value `0`. Show us the code as [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Do you know what the `2` means in `vector<int> v(2)`?  Do you know how to find out?  Do you know how your program behaves when you change that number?

Comment: This is explained in any beginner level [C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: See [What is `vector<int> v(N)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35478657/what-is-difference-between-vectorint-vn-and-vector-int-v-n)

Answer (score 1):

The two zeroes are there, because you created a vector with two zeroes. You could overwrite them, but `push_back` adds another value instead of overwriting existing elements.